# Default memory block for Unix/Linux threads?

Tags: windows, linux, multithreading, unix, memory

Does anybody know how much default memory is allocated to a thread created on Unix/Linux operating system? 
For windows xp OS i found that it allocates a memory block of 1MB, is it correct?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There's not going to be a single answer to that question.

In fact there's not even a single answer on Windows. Different executables specify different stack limits. And even within a single process, individual threads can have different stack limits.

And it gets even more complicated when you factor in the differences between .net and native executables. Rather strangely .net executables commit the entire stack allocation for each thread as soon as the thread starts. On the other hand, native executables reserve the stack allocation and then commit memory on demand using guard pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can see how much space is allocated for thread stacks (measured in kbytes) with `ulimit -s`.

Quoting from the [`pthread_create(3)` manpage](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html):

> On Linux/x86-32, the default stack
>   size for a new thread is 2 megabytes.
>   Under the NPTL threading
>   implementation, if the RLIMIT_STACK
>   soft resource limit at the time the
>   program started has any value other
>   than "unlimited", then it determines
>   the default stack size of new threads.
>   Using pthread_attr_setstacksize(3),
>   the stack size attribute can be
>   explicitly set in the attr argument
>   used to create a thread, in order to
>   obtain a stack size other than the
>   default.

Comment: `ulimit -s` only returns the maximum stack size; not the default.

Comment: if a thread is created without specifying stack size, ulimit -s should return default size, is this correct?

Comment: @reonyang: yes, correct, (unless `ulimit -s` returns `unlimited`)

Comment: Actually, i dont have unix/linux at my use, can some one quote some numbers here?

Comment: @reonyang: depends on distro, typically 8 MB